# How to add two time values in ssis?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

This is my scenario

```
Value 1 : 15:55:10  (HH:MM:SS)
Value 2 : 05:15:55  (HH:MM:SS)

ADD = Value 1+ Value 2
```

Expected Answer:  21:11:05

Comment: So these are durations you're adding, rather than times? What do you want to happen if it goes beyond 24 hours?

Comment: we have to consider date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx). This explains how to add dates in sql.

Edit: At Flem's suggestion I am including a bit more information :)

You could use the DATEADD and DATEPART functions to add the times together (Assuming you are using datetime types).

```
value = DATEADD(hour,DATEPART(hour,Value1),Value2);
value = DATEADD(minute,DATEPART(minute,Value1),value);
value = DATEADD(second,DATEPART(second,Value1),value);
```

These could be chained into a query fairly trivially (Even if the code is not pretty :) )

Comment: You should provide the relevant content from the link in your post.